# What TPS can dynamodb handle?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, bigdata

I thought NoSQL database such as Cassandra or DynamoDB can handle 10,000 QPS or TPS. But when I recently looked at some DynamoDB configurations, i often saw less than 100 TPS. Is this 100 TPS for one thread or all threads? Did i miss anything? Searched AWS documentation but didn't find solution for similar questions. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the main points of NoSQL databases like Cassandra, Scylla or DynamoDB, is that they are scalable - they use a cluster of nodes which can grow to allow (in theory) almost unlimited number of requests per second. So you can handle 100 rps, 10,000 rps, or even 10,000,000 rps, depending on the cluster's size (and size of each individual node). In the software-as-a-service DynamoDB, you don't see the actual cluster behind the server, and instead you need to "provision" how many requests per second you want to allow.

I don't know how you provisioned the setup which gave you 100 rps. You may also have measured this throughput wrong: You mentioned threads. Are you talking about **client** threads? Because obviously, if you have just one client thread, you aren't measuring throughput at all, but rather latency: If the client thread sends one request and waits for it to be replied before sending the next request, then if your requests have 10ms latency (even because of network latency), you can only do 100 of them from that one thread. But you could have 1000 of these threads achieving a throughput of 100,000 requests per second. You can also have an event-driven thread, which sends many requests before waiting for them to complete, instead of just one request.

Comment: Thanks nyh! Yes I am talking about client thread. For example, if my latency is 20ms and I need do 500 request per second. I have to provide multiple(at least 10) threads. This will require more charges?

Comment: Yes, if latency is 20ms and a single thread just does a serial request-response loop, then each such thread only does 50 requests per second, and you need more of these threads to get to higher throughput. But "more charges" for what? DynamoDB charges you for the requests made - it has no idea how many threads your client has, it's just your own implementation details. Your client can also achieve high concurrency with just a single thread, if you program it right.

Comment: As of about 2-3 weeks ago, you no longer have to provision RCU and WCU up front. You can configure tables to have 'on-demand' provision. This is a great change, the idea of buying a certain amount of cloud service up front was strange.

Answer (score 6):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html

There aren't any limits. The maximum throughput you can provision per table is 40,000 RCUs (read per second) and 40,000 WCUs (writes per second) by default. But that's only a limit to prevent users accidentally provisioning excessive throughput, you can simply request a higher limit is applied to your account.